# Is there a Catalog of Debian packages

Tags: debian, package

The Debian site is great http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages, and I'm aware of the search facilities, but I really want a complete catalog of packages/files/architectures in some consumable format - xml, json, csv etc.

Can anyone direct me to one?

Comment: Great, that's just the thing. If you enter it as an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may download the packages list from their repos.

```
http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/[release]/[main|contrib|non-free]/Contents-[arch].gz
```

Example: [stable main amd64](http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz)

A good starting point for getting more informations would be [here](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat).

Comment: Using http://http.debian.net removes the need to care about the name of the mirror you want to download from.